# CSS alignment issue - not able to keep the div in same row when trying to make page responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive design here http://bloggingtopsecrets.com/development/testblog/ but unfortunately not able to keep the "services" div elements in same row (all 3 should be in same row). Right now one of them is coming to new row which is making the .all-posts class to be on right hand side. How to fix this keeping the responsiveness of the theme ?

here is the jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/icyborg7/b53zN/1/ (though you can check the whole site from above url too)

```
.all-posts {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBEBEB;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 11px;
width: 343px;
}
.services {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
width: 358px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post some of your code, fiddle will be better

Comment: @Amarnath - actually you can see the whole site in the url above, still let me try to create a fiddle too

Comment: @Amarnath - here is the jsfidle code http://jsfiddle.net/icyborg7/b53zN/1/

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b53zN/12/ and let me know is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps
**HTML**

```
     <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="services">
        <img src="http://bloggingtopsecrets.com/development/testblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/design.png">
            <h1>DESIGN</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
    <div class="services">
        <img src="http://bloggingtopsecrets.com/development/testblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/consultancy.png">
        <h1>CONSULTANCY</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
        <div class="services" >
        <img src="http://bloggingtopsecrets.com/development/testblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/maintenance.png">
        <h1>MAINTENANCE</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
        </div>

            <div class="all-posts">             

<h1 class="entry-title">
<a href="http://example.com" rel="bookmark">Example 0</a>
</h1>
<h1 class="entry-title">
<a href="http://example.com" rel="bookmark">Example 1</a>
</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .wrapper
{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1200px;
    padding:0px;
}
.all-posts {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBEBEB;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 11px;
width: 343px;
}
.services {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
width: 358px;
}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/b53zN/12/

Comment: Hi is it responsive since we are using  width:1200px; in wrapper ?

Comment: you can change the size of wrapper as you wish and dont forget to divide the size of wrapper by 3 and assign that to services class

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<div class="services" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%;">
<div class="services" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%;">
<div class="services" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%;">
```

Remove `float:left` and change `width: 125px !important` in `.service` class

Comment: why have you called class here and coded for inline css too??

Comment: inline css he should be adding in `.services` class